# Node.js get same instance of module accross different classes

Tags: node.js

I've a main class (app.js) where I declared an instance of `socket-io` and I would like to know how is possible to get same instance of `socket-io` inside another classes.

app.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
//initialize socket and more related do web socket
```

routes.js

```
var io = ?? //How get same var io from app.js?
```

On Node.js, is possible to do that? I need to manipulate some informations from `socket-io` but I would like to avoid write a single file with all logic inside.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file `routes.js` and this is a file inside which you want to access the instance of `socket-io` which you have created on `app.js`. Then you can pass this `var io` inside the  `routes.js` file that will pass the same instance of `socket-io` like this,

**Inside app.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

//pass the `io` inside the route file
require('routes')(io);
```

**Inside routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
   //your route codes here that can access `io`
};
```